# Viewing memory leaks in Xcode Instruments

Tags: c++, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments, xcode-instruments

I am new to Xcode Instruments. How can I see a simple memory leak difference
in the following 2 programs by using the Leak template :

```
int main()
{
    int* pp =  new int[50000000];
    for(int i =0;i<50000000;i++){
        pp[i] = i;
    }
}
```

```
int main()
{
    int* pp = new int[1];
    pp[0] = 10;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/InstrumentsQuickStart/InstrumentsQuickStart.html

Comment: in each of the above cases i get only 1.5kB of leak ,which is same for the following code too:`int main(){ //blank}` , there must be a difference ?